# Mongo db Atlas 3.6.5 authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am pretty new to node.js,am trying to write data to a free online mongo db atlas using mongoose,however i keep getting Authentication failed despite editing mongo db settings to connect from anywhere and also using correct username and password for the db user.

Here is my app.js file where i connect to mongo db
app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const productRoutes= require('./api/routes/products');
const ordersRoutes= require('./api/routes/orders');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://hilary:'+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW+'@node-rest-dnqwa.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true').catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,res,next) =>{
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization');

if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,PATCH');
    return res.status(200).json({});

}
    next();
});

app.use('/products',productRoutes);
app.use('/orders',ordersRoutes);

app.use((req,res,next) => {
    const error= new Error('not found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);

});

app.use((error,req,res,next) =>{
   res.status(error.status || 500);
   res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message 

        }
   })


})


module.exports = app;
```

i get this error in my terminal:

```
{ MongoError: authentication fail
    at C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:1430:15
    at C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:877:7
    at C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:853:20
    at finish (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:174:16)
    at handleEnd (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:184:7)
    at C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:289:15
    at C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:544:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'authentication fail',
  errors:
   [ { name: 'node-rest-shard-00-00-dnqwa.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] },
     { name: 'node-rest-shard-00-02-dnqwa.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] } ] }
```

I am certain am using correct name and password so why cant it authenticate me,server runs on my localhost

EDIT
So i followed link to docs and now connect this way:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://hilary:'+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW+'@localhost:27017/test').catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I then get this error in terminal:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:505:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:329:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
```

Comment: what is your mongoose version? and make sure your password and username should not contain `+,-,=,@`

Comment: Yes my password is all letters and numbers,my mongoose version 5.1.5

Comment: I could not able to see any port host in your url and also you are merging both mongoose and mongodb... you cannot use mongodb driver to make a connection using mongoose... You need to put some url to make a connection to the database... You can find it here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Thanks,So i follow the docs on basic connect with mongoose now i get Slash in host identifier error

Comment: Please post your error in the question and explain it as well

Comment: please have a look at my edit

Comment: try with this mongoose.connect(`mongodb://hilary:'+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW+'@localhost:27017/db_name)`

Comment: I get  MongoNetworkError,check the edit

Comment: ok great!!! Now your mongod service hasn't been started... Start it using sudo service mongod start... or tell me what OS you are using

Comment: Am using windows 10

Comment: go to your mongodb folder bin file and start the mongod service

Comment: So i run the mongod app,and then i get authentication failed error

Comment: are you sure you have set the username and password? Try with simple `mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name)`

Comment: That works! Thats what i tried and it solved thanks for docs

Comment: ohhh!!! that's great... Nice efforts... cheers

Comment: But with my correct password it isnt authenticating,so sad

Comment: I'v just realised this connects to my local database,i want to connect to a free online one i created,thats why authentication fails,how do i connect to that one,thats the username and password am using

Comment: you need to put the host and port along with username and password to connect to that database... mentioned here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Please give me a short example maybe i dont get it

Comment: `mongoose.connect(mongodb://user_name:pass@host:port/db_name)` you need replace username password host port and db_name here

Answer (score 0):

What worked was a slight variation from the mongoose docs,it was suggested on the Atlas server,for everyone who has Mongodb 3.4+ connect using the regular mongo db driver even when using mongoose, my connection string looks like:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://hilary:<password>@node-rest-dnqwa.mongodb.net').catch(err => console.log(err));`